# Android database transactions

Tags: android, database, transactions, sqlite

I am new to Android programming and am trying to understand the best practices.

I want to do multiple inserts into two different database tables, but as one transaction (as the tables shared a foreign key). I want my function to return a result so that I can display a Toast or something to say that an error occurred, otherwise I want to return the row ID of the first insert.

I believe one way of doing this is sort-of as follows (Disclaimer: psuedo-ish code, probably won't compile!):

```
Long result = -1;
myDatabase.beginTransaction();
try {
   // Insert into first table
   ContentValue someValues = new ContentValues();
   someValues.put("dbfield1", 1);
   result = myDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_1, null, someValues);

   if (-1 != result ) {         
       // Insert into second table
       someValues.clear();
       someValues.put("dbfield2", 2);

       if( myDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_2, null, someValues) < 0 ) {
           result = -1;
       }
   }

   mDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch(Exception e) {
    // An error occurred
    result = -1;
} finally {
   mDatabase.endTransaction();
}
```

Is there a simpler/better way of doing this?

Comment: Looks OK to me, just be sure to do your database work from outside the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `bulkInsert` inside your ContentProvider
your Code looks fine. The Method should return the inserted Rows Value but you can customize that so you return only the first ID.

```
public int bulkInsert(Uri uri, ContentValues[] values) {
    Log.e("BULK", "Bulk insert started for URI" + uri.toString());
    bulkSqlDB = database.getWritableDatabase();
    int numInserted;

    bulkSqlDB.beginTransaction();
    try {
        for (ContentValues cv : values) {
            insert(uri, cv);
        }
        bulkSqlDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
        numInserted = values.length;
    } finally {
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        bulkSqlDB.endTransaction();
    }
    return numInserted;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do I not need to check the return code of the inserts to ensure that I do not call setTransactionSuccessful() if one of them fail (so that only some, not all of the inserts are comitted)? or would an exception be thrown upon a failure which is handle by the try/finally?

Comment: Yep, the second, because its inside one big transaction, the insert code throws a exception so setTransactionSuccessful(); is not called and numInserted = 0 is returned. But you can define your own rules for bulkInserts, you can make it 'Greedy' so that only the inserts that failed are left out. If thats the case you must count the successful inserts.

Comment: Thanks so much. Sorry to be a pain and keep asking basic questions - I am a newbie!. One last thing - my code is a DbAdapter (similar to the one in the Android notepad tutorial) not in a ContentProvider. I assume that insert will throw an exception in the same way in a transaction in my DbAdapter (i.e. it is not specific to doing the transaction in the bulkInsert method in the ContentProvider)?.